# FullCalendar Date differs when stored and retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar and my event object's start date is stored into the database with

```
copiedEventObject.start = date;
```

I later retrieve it and initialize my calendar with:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getCalendarEventsData",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                calendarStoredEvents = $.map(msg.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        title: item.EventTitle,
                        start: item.start,
                        id: item.EventID,
                        staffID: item.staffID
                    };
                });
                initializeCalendar(calendarStoredEvents);
            }
        });
```

Where item.start is:

> 2013-06-30T16:00:00.000Z

The problem now is that. **If I stored my event object when it is one Wednesday, it retrieves and is displayed on Tuesday instead.** I read up a little and it has something to do with the TimeZone. I have tried adding:

> ignoretimezone = false (which failed, then tried toggling it to true)
>
> ignoretimezone = true (which also failed, then tried to add timezone)
>
> currentTimezone: 'Asia/Singapore' (which didn't work as well)

This is the value that is stored in the database:

```
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                // write to database
                var eventID = copiedEventObject.id;
                var staffID = copiedEventObject.staffID;
                var start = copiedEventObject.start;
                var end = copiedEventObject.end;
                var allDay = copiedEventObject.allDay;
```

*Edit*

My website is hosted in Azure, so i guess the time comes from the server:

When I drop an event

> ( drop: function (date, allDay))

i used alert(start) and it displayed (my client time)

> Wed Jul 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

I write into the database in my C# code behind:

```
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PCSDB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CalendarData (EventID, staffID, start) VALUES (@EventID, @staffID, @start)", conn))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", eventID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffID", staffID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);

        int queryResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
```

When i check the database the start value becomes

> 2013-07-16T16:00:00.000Z

*EDIT*
I saved the right date in my database after changing to datetime.

Now i have a problem converting it for the object. I used:

```
  var parsedDate = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(item.start);
  var formatedDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(parsedDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Passed in

> 17/7/2013 12:00:00 AM Becomes 07-05-2014

Comment: What is the data type on your calendar date within your database? Do you do any conversion of the date before saving it into the database?

Comment: nvarchar, i just passed in the variable and saved what i got

Comment: @BloopieBloops - Are you really storing a date into an `nvarchar` type?  That is not so good.  What database are you using? There are always better types for dates.  If it's SQL Server, you should probably use a `datetime` or `datetime2` type.

Comment: should i try changing to datetime first?

Comment: Oh dear! Changing to datetime stored the right date in my database. But now the problem is that FullCalender is not reading the 17/7/2013 12:00:00 AM format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the time is stored in your database isn't relevant.  It matters only how the time is transmitted over your API and into FullCalendar.  Assuming the exact string you provided `"2013-06-30T16:00:00.000Z"` is what is passed into FullCalendar, then the behavior you described makes sense.  The UTC time you provided is being adjusted to the user's local time zone.

FullCalendar displays a calendar in the local time zone of the person who is viewing it.  There is no setting to view the calendar in UTC, or in any other time zone.  There is some information [here](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=280) where they mention being "timezone agnostic".  You can think of it this way in terms of how the calendar is drawn, but you will always still have the local time zone when looking at any `Date` object, because that's how JavaScript works.

You have some options:

- Set the [`ignoreTimezone`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/) option to `true`, and pass your input values in as strings rather than dates.
- Pass the values as strings without a time zone offset  (remove the `Z`)
- Pass the values as strings with the correct time zone offset for the person viewing the data.
- Pass the values as `Date` objects that have already been adjusted for the local time zone.

The `currentTimezone` option is not part of FullCalendar.  It's in the `gcal.js` addon, for hooking FullCalender up to Google Calendar over the gcal 1.0 api.  It simply passes that parameter to Google as `ctz` in the querystring.  It only affects the way the data is returned from Google.  It doesn't do anything in FullCalendar itself.

Comment: I have set ignoreTimezone all to true, tried removing Z from the timezone offset but both do not work. When i dropped my event into the calendar on day 16, it is written as day 15 in my database already - @Matt Johnson

Comment: The problem may lie on the server side.  Please show us exactly the value coming out of this code, and how it is being received and stored in the database.  (edit your question)

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the date to format [formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) before you save it to database. The event will only accept formatts like this dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00.

I have this in my select method, so maybe you are not fetching the event object properly.
This works fine for me.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay){

      var startdate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "dd-MM-yyyy");
      var enddate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "dd-MM-yyyy");     

      alert(startdate);
      alert(enddate);
 }
```

This will show a date like 15-07-2013.

Comment: C.I added 

    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(copiedEventObject.start, 'dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00');

before writing it to the database, when retrieve doesnt even appear

Comment: Ups i'm sorry if you miss understood the 00:00:00 i meant hh:mm:ss :P

Comment: hey, i updated the post, i tried the formatDate but the year became 2014 or 2015